# How can I get tags of 0/1 from list of names?

Tags: python

I have list with files names

```
['dog7', 'cat5', 'dog77', 'dog44', 'cat5']
```

I want to classify dog as 1 and cat as 0

How can I get list of `1/0` from that list ?
i.e `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]` ?

I wrote this code:

```
res = []
for i in a:
    if "dog" in i:
        res.append(1)
    else:
        res.append(0)
res
```

Is there a more professional code to write this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a comprehension:

```
res = [int("dog" in i) for i in a]
```

This uses the fact that `1 == True` and `0 == False`. Depending on your real use case and logic, since you should try to be as specific and performant as possible, your example data suggests that the following might be more to the point:

```
res = [int(i.startswith("dog")) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the files are either cat or dog, I would use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
file_names = ['dog7', 'cat5', 'dog77', 'dog44', 'cat5']  

res = [1 if 'dog' in name else 0 for name in file_names]
```

I think this is a bit easier to read and understand than using int() to turn 'truthiness' into a 1.